Browsing problem after updating Ubuntu 24.04 in September
Since the last update of my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (which went well without apparent problems) I have problems with browsing the internet. On Firefox, Chromium, Google Chrome and Vivaldi I get popups with messages which don't tell me anything I could use to correct something.
The only browser that works normally is Opera. All the others show an error message as soon as I open a website or refresh a page.
Something to do with reading some lines and columns of some API or file, which I shall allow or dismiss:
askubuntu.com
undefined
Calling file: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=44cbb4d4d062 Line 1 Column 42286

and the next popup reads:
Do you want to allow reading via the DOMRect-API?
Calling file: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js Line 2 Column 54435

I usually click OK, and sometimes this dismisses the warning and I can go on, but other times the next one pops up and the next and so on. It has nothing do do with any add-ons - I have systematically deactivated all of them and the problem still occurs.
I can provide screenshots if necessary. Do you have any ideas?
I have already tried to update manually from the terminal, but to no avail.
